# useState, Checkbox wont change to false,

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, react-hooks, material-ui

I want to enable/disable a button, if a person checked all checkboxes, but my console.log says all time `true`, anyway if it is checked or not.  Is there another way then:

```
    setChecked1(prevValue => !prevValue)
    console.log(preCondition1)
  }
```

i like to use useState obj for shorter script:

```js
const [checked, setChecked] = useState({
    ableStatus: true,
    unableStatus: "",
    preCondition1: "",
    preCondition2: "true",
    preCondition3: "true",
    preCondition4: "true",
    preCondition5: "true"

  });
  const [buttonState, setButtonState] = useState(true);
  

  const handleButtonState = () => {
    if ( checked.preCondition1 === true) {
      setButtonState(false);
    } else {
      setButtonState(true);
    }
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setChecked((prevState) => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        [name]: value,
      };
    });
    console.log(checked.preCondition1)
    handleButtonState();
    }


 const {    
    preCondition1,
    preCondition2,
    preCondition3,
    preCondition4,
    preCondition5,
   
    
  } = checked;
...

<Checkbox
                defaultChecked="checked"
                onChange={handleChange}
                value={preCondition1}
                name="preCondition1"
                inputProps={{ "aria-label": "controlled" }}
                sx={{
                  color: red[200],
                  "&.Mui-checked": {
                    color: green[800],
                  },
                }}
              />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer:

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
      setValues((prevState) => {
        const [name] = e.target
        return{    
          ...prevState,
          [name]: !prevState[name]
      
        }})
        test()
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

for booleans in react state you can simply do a:

```
SetState(!state);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thx for answering - i googled since your answer, but i have no clue, how to do so. - how or where do i use setSate?

Comment: So, instead of using a if & else statement you can do the setState(!state). What this does is just like flipping a light switch. If state is true it will set the state to false and vice versa. You can either do it inside your handle change and get rid of the handbleButtonState, or replace the if & else with the setState. :)

Comment: I see what u mean, thx for that :) This function validate if the button is enabled/disabled.  The function below  - handleChange  - is my problem- When it is checked or not, the console say all the time, it's true. - I appreciate your effort <3